# Accessing const enums in Angular html template

Tags: html, angular, typescript, templates, enums

Assume I have a const enum:

```
export const enum MyConstEnum{
    Value1 = 'Value1',
    Value2 = 'Value2',
    Value3 = 'Value3'
}
```

Now I want to use it in my Angular template:

```
<span *ngIf="name === MyConstEnum.Value1">This has some value</value>
```

However, this is not possible, because `MyConstEnum` is not seen by template.
So the question is how to access `const enum` in Angular html template?

If enum won't be const like this

```
export enum MyEnum{
    Value1 = 'Value1',
    Value2 = 'Value2',
    Value3 = 'Value3'
}
```

there is a solution to create property in templates' component

```
  public get MyEnumInComponent() {
    return MyEnum;
  }
```

and `MyEnumInComponent` will be accessible in HTML.
However, I have `const enum`.

For this I cannot defined property like above. What is the solution (except changing `const enum` to `enum`)?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the problem here? I don't get what is not working and what you actually want to accomplish.

Comment: I can see here on this link 'https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/25963' that it is an issue and it needs a fix. Also some have suggested a work around see if t helps.

Comment: @TarangRathod can you show an example, please? It is "const enum" not "enum"?

Comment: @PhilippMeissner check my solution!

Answer (score 3):

It will be possible if TypeScript won't erase const enum declaration in the emitted JavaScript code.

There is dedicated compiler options `preserveConstEnums` for that:

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

Now, let's say you have

**const-enum.ts**

```
export const enum MyConstEnum {
    Value1 = 'Value1',
    Value2 = 'Value2',
    Value3 = 'Value3'
}
```

You can import it in component like:

```
import * as constEnumModule from './const-enum';

class SomeComponent {
  MyConstEnum = (constEnumModule as any).MyConstEnum;
}
```

It finally it should be available in your template for this component:

```
<span *ngIf="name === MyConstEnum.Value1">This has some value</value>
```

Comment: As I undestand this, `preserveConstEnums` replaces const enums with lookup tables instead of inlining the enum values, which is the main purpose of the const enums, at this point you'd rather have non-const enums instead of const enums.
`preserveConstEnums` should be mainly used for debugging purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I can see on this link https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/25963
that it is known issue and it is specifically with const enum.

[image]

```
There is also a work arround suggested in the discussion on the url:
templateImports: [someConstant, UserStatus, isDevMode]
This would not work, but the below could:

templateImports: {someConstant, UserStatus, isDevMode}
```

Comment: What is templateImports? Where is definition of templateImports somehwere in Angular docs?

Comment: Have you tried it yourself? That was only suggestions and it wasn't implemented

Comment: I have not tried I said I came across this information if it might help

Comment: What you linked to is a feature request, not a bug report. The templateImports functionality does not exist.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a property of the same name as the enum inside your component and you'd be able to access the enum just as you would within your ts file. You can do this by either importing it or declaring it within the ts file if preferred:

```
import { MyConstEnum } from './enum'

OR

enum MyConstEnum {
    Value1 = 'Value1',
    Value2 = 'Value2',
    Value3 = 'Value3'
}

@Component({
    selector: 'app-my-component',
    templateUrl: './my-component.page.html',
    styleUrls: ['./my-component.page.scss'],
})
export class MyComponent {
    MyConstEnum = MyConstEnum;
    ...
}
```

And within the html template:

```
<span *ngIf="name === MyConstEnum.Value1">{{ MyConstEnum.Value1 }}</value>
```

Comment: This is not using a `const enum`, you just named your enum `constEnum`... that does NOT make it `const`. The issue is with enums using the `const` keyword, as you can't reassign them like you did in your class.

Comment: You're right, misread the question. Either way I hope it helps people do it a bit more simply than the last function in the OP's question.

Answer (score -2):

I bypassed this issue by replacing my const enum types to static properties inside classes like this:

```
export class MyEnum{
    static  Value1 = 'Value1',
    static  Value2 = 'Value2',
    static  Value3 = 'Value3'
}
```

Comment: how is that better then a normal js-object?