# Enumerations use in Angular HTML

Tags: angular, typescript, angular13, typescript-decorator

I have an enum and would like to use it in an Angular 13 component.

Enum:

```
export enum PropertyCode {
  ALPHA = 'ALPHA',
  BETA = 'BETA',
  ZETA = 'ZETA',
}
```

TS:

```
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';
import { PropertyCode } from './property-code';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {

  isHidden(code: PropertyCode): boolean {
    switch (code) {
      case PropertyCode.ALPHA:        return false;
      case PropertyCode.BETA:        return true;
      case PropertyCode.ZETA:        return false;
    }
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngIf="!isHidden(PropertyCode.ALPHA)">Alpha</li>
  <li *ngIf="!isHidden(PropertyCode.BETA)">Beta</li>
  <li *ngIf="!isHidden(PropertyCode.ZETA)">Zeta</li>
</ul>
```

Result:

[image]

Sandbox [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-1wd2of?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

**However, I don't want to create a property corresponding to that enum in the component...**

It has any meaning for me, because there is no specific information to keep in, and I would like to use the UpperCase letter in the HTML, as the normal enum.

So I tried the decorator

```
import { PropertyCode } from './property-code';

export function PropertyCodeAware(constructor: Function) {
  constructor.prototype.PropertyCode = PropertyCode;
}
```

and decorated the component, but that does not seem to help

```
@PropertyCodeAware
export class AppComponent {
```

Comment: Well, the property seem to be there, but the compiler doesn't know that. If you can find a way to instruct the compiler not to worry so much about that property not being explicitly declared, the error would most likely go away.

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu I don't have much experience to talking to compiler

Comment: Makes sense. I don't think you can get around this in a clean way. Maybe disable template checking, strict type checking, etc...

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu something like here ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/63337582/961631

Comment: What's the problem with adding `PropertyCode` as component class's property?

Comment: @DimaParzhitsky, you can't add PropertyCode property, because the PropertyCode is already reserved to the enumeration name

Comment: @serge You can.

Comment: It seems that Angular's compiler cannot idenfity inizialization of variables in custom decorators. This is just my conclusion after some tests. The only "clean" way I found out to works is by extending a class that has the declaration of that enum in it. I suggest you to open an issue in Github, you will for sure answered better than here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Genially simple solution [proposed by Jorge Mussato](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59289208/961631), in the `.component.ts`

```
public get PropertyCode() {
  return PropertyCode; 
}
```

No need of decorators (to remove)

Comment: This is the same as `public PropertyCode = PropertyCode;`

Comment: @DimaParzhitsky, no, because you have `import { PropertyCode } from './property-code';`

Comment: Well, I just changed the sandox, and it worked for me.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jx462h?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: @DimaParzhitsky, is true that it seem possible... However, if you read the OP, when you add a property, you like have some specific info to keep for your component. By eg the property "Name" keeps the Name of that specific component. However, "PropertyCode" you have no specific "PropertyCode" for that component

Comment: If you care about semantic meaning, then the implementation should be changed quite significantly: both `isHidden` and `PropertyCode` don't belong to the template

Comment: To do that, you create a collection (array) of data items, designate each of the items with the enum value (`{ type: PropertyCode.ALPHA, … }`), then, separately, create a mapping of `type` to `isHidden` (`{ [PropertyCode.ALPHA]: true, … }`), then combine these two structures to create a filtered collection, and _only then_ give the filtered collection to the template.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jx462h?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: `isHidden` is a method, incorporates some component logic about the visibility of a specific element of the component. It's a legal and logic member of component. However  the current value of `PropertyCode` property would have any meaning for a component instance

Answer (score 0):

You have to create property in your AppComponent

```
propertyCode = PropertyCode;
```

than you can use it in your app.component.html template

```
<ul>
  <li *ngIf="!isHidden(propertyCode.ALPHA)">Alpha</li>
  <li *ngIf="!isHidden(propertyCode.BETA)">Beta</li>
  <li *ngIf="!isHidden(propertyCode.ZETA)">Zeta</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: _However, I don't want to create a property corresponding to that enum in the component..._ OP wrote it pretty clearly.

Comment: thanks @JacopoSciampi, I edited the OP to stress that

Comment: I think this is the right approach.
You should be able to use the Uppercase version...



    PropertyCode = PropertyCode;

Comment: @mrdnk a property of something, means that that something has some property, we could change. In our case, the PropertyCode is not a property of the component.

Comment: @serge I understand what you’re saying, but this just a case of that’s how Angular works. You are essentially creating a reference to the underline enum. I want to be the other way too, but it’s not! I come from a C# background, where you don’t need to do this, but this is just the way Angular works.

Comment: @mrdnk having a getter seems to me a cleaner alternative to a writable property.